# Curl argument in nvm insallation

Tags: bash, curl

The node version manager (nvm) package (https://github.com/creationix/nvm) 
uses the following command to install the package:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash
```

What does the additonal minus `-` mean after the argument `-o`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash
```

The `-o` argument defines the output of `curl`. By specifying `-`, curl will redirect the output to stdout. This is why you are able to pipe that to `bash` and have it execute the `install.sh` shell script in one line. This has the added benefit of not leaving the `install.sh` file on the machine's file system.

Comment: Isn't the default behaviour of curl to output to stdout?

Comment: @DenniedeLange Yes, but adding `-o-` will force output to stdout. It's likely there to be through. (Although piping curl to bash is generally viewed as 'unsafe')